# Wordpress theme showing blank page

Tags: php, functions, permalinks

Something is wrong to my installed theme, because when I am clicking on *Visit Site* than its showing blank page.

No error and no content, no navigation nothing to display.

There is link below :-

http://www.gate7infotech.com/projects/development/derrick_payne/

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Comment: It could be one of million things......

Comment: I have tried this debug code but still not showing any error.

Comment: Edit source code in a browser and you'll see a warning `Warning:  file_put_contents(.... etc` plus your page does not have any content, just a background kinda white.

Comment: Where to put code in browser. means in `head` tag or `body` tag ?

Comment: It seems that you have a coding error in your `page.php`, can you switch to 2014 and see if the problem still exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme is trying to retrieve data from Twitter and store it. It is failing to do so for whatever reason.

Contact the author of the theme and have them fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This error arise when you install new WordPress Themes or WordPress upgrade. So to handle this error simply just navigate to wp-content/theme directory and try to rename it, hope this  will solve this issue